# Encrypt/Decrypt DB passwords config file

Tags: linux, unix

`I have a file with DB passwords as below

```
user1=ABC
user1pass = Monday11!
user1dbname = TEST
this is test line
user2=DEF
user2pass=Tuesday11!
user2dbname=TEST2
```

I want to encrypt all the password fields (identified by "pass"), encrypt them in the same file. The output should look like this:

```
user1pass =%8hjdsk=
this is test line
user2pass=!yhdskk*&=
```

I want to pass these encrypted passwords to the sqlplus command in the linux script. I am not sure but probably I need to decrypt them before passing it to sqlplus.
`

```
${SQLPLUS} -s ${user1pass}/${user1pass}@${user1dbname}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

I tried using binaryascii but it didn't work in linux
Also tried byte^encryption_key and it did not work `

Comment: Please [edit] your question and copy&paste the exact commands you tried and explain in what way "it didn't work". If you get an error message, copy&paste it, if you get a wrong result, show the actual and expected result.